RestOperation exchange method returning Http 406
I'm trying to hit a POST request using org.springframework.web.client.RestOperations, This will return me a bearer token.
{
    "access_token": "<token>",
    "expires_in": 300
}

I have created a POJO to map to this response.
TokenResponse.class
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
        "access_token",
        "expires_in"
})
public class TokenResponse {

    @JsonProperty("access_token")
    private String accessToken;
    @JsonProperty("expires_in")
    private Integer expiresIn;

    @JsonProperty("access_token")
    public String getAccessToken() {
        return accessToken;
    }

    @JsonProperty("access_token")
    public void setAccessToken(String accessToken) {
        this.accessToken = accessToken;
    }

    @JsonProperty("expires_in")
    public Integer getExpiresIn() {
        return expiresIn;
    }

    @JsonProperty("expires_in")
    public void setExpiresIn(Integer expiresIn) {
        this.expiresIn = expiresIn;
    }
}

When I try to hit this POST request with the below code, it's returning me an error - org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$NotAcceptable: 406 Not Acceptable: [no body]
ResponseEntity<T> response = restOperations.exchange(
                    uri,
                    HttpMethod.POST,
                    new HttpEntity<>(body, headers),
                    TokenResponse.class
            );

I know the error says there's no body, but when I change the last parameter in the above method call to String.class, I'm getting a Http 200 along with the correct response body. where am I going wrong?

What is the headers information you are passing?

A single header, content-type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded and a MultiValueMap body

Can you add  headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));  param also in headers, and then try the response type as TokenResponse.class.

No luck, same error

If it helps, this is the content-type in the response headers - application/vnd.appd.cntrl+json;v=1

I've got this info from Postman, when I hit the request manually

The problem is that your server side is not able to understand your TokenResponse.class response type, so it is throwing this error.

You don't need @JsonProperty on getter and setter. just keep it over the fields, add a default constructor and try again once. If this also won't work, also check once on the server side if you are giving the correct response type.
